# Delay queue function works only on first iteration

Tags: jquery, queue

I have following chunk of code:

```
$('.mobileBox').on('click', function() {
            $(this).toggleClass('expand');
            $(".mobile_nav").toggleClass('displayMobileNav');
            $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-ellipsis-h fa-times');
            //delay animations for 1 second in order to let width expand until the end 
            $(this).delay(1000).queue(function() {
                $(".mobile_nav li").each(function (i) { 
                    $(this).attr("style", "-webkit-animation-delay:" + i * 200 + "ms;"
                     + "-moz-animation-delay:" + i * 200 + "ms;"
                     + "-o-animation-delay:" + i * 200 + "ms;"
                     + "animation-delay:" + i * 200 + "ms;");
                    if (i == $(".mobile_nav li").size() -1) {
                        $(".mobile_nav").addClass("play");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

Please refer to this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kx27vt6n/)

How can I reset delay queue as it only works for the first time?

Comment: What do you mean by "it only works for the first time"? Can you include `html`, `css` at Question? , create stacksnippets to demonstrate?

Comment: delay only works for once, if I click it to expand it again it doesn't "wait" for expand to finish

Comment: Where is queue dequeued?

Comment: _"it doesn't "wait" for expand to finish"_ What is "expand to finish"? Are you trying to call a function at conclusion of `transition` event?

Comment: Are you trying to call a function when the last `li` `css` animation is complete?

Comment: 'li' elements are supposed to wait 'expand' to finish animation and it works only for the first iteration. by clicking on the 'mobileBox' to expand again the 'li' elements are ignoring delay. Please check fiddle provided for reference, and there is no de-queueing because the outcome is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a name for the delay and queue, use `transitionend` event, `.one()` at `.expand` element to call `.queue()` to set a function to call for each `li` element using `$.map()`; at `animationend` event of each `li` element, call `next` function in queue using `.one()`.

When queue is complete use `.promise()`, `.then()`, remove `style` attribute or set `style` attribute containing `animation` properties, values to empty string at the elements.

```js
$(".mobile_navigation").addClass("mobileBox");
var li = $(".mobile_nav li");
var mobileBox = $(".mobileBox");
var mobileNav = $(".mobile_nav");
mobileBox.on('click', function() {
  // remove `style` attribute at `li` elements
  li.removeAttr("style");
  $(this).toggleClass('expand');

  mobileNav.toggleClass('displayMobileNav');
  $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-ellipsis-h fa-times');

});

mobileBox.parent()
  .on("transitionend", ".expand", function(event) {
    // do stuff at `transitionend` event of `.expand`,
    // queue a function for each `.mobile_nav li` element;
    // at `animationend` event of each `li` element
    // call next function in "transition" queue
    mobileBox
      .queue("transition", $.map(li, function(el) {
        return function(next) {
          $(el).attr("style",
           `-webkit-animation-delay:200ms;
            -moz-animation-delay:200ms;
            -o-animation-delay:200ms;
            animation-delay:200ms;
            -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
            -moz-animation-play-state: running;
            -o-animation-play-state: running;
            animation-play-state: running;`)
            .one("animationend", next)
        }
      }))
      .dequeue("transition")
      .promise("transition")
      .then(function() {
        // remove `style` attribute at `li` elements
        li.removeAttr("style")
      })
  })
```

```css
.mobileBox {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: rgb(52, 152, 219);
  z-index: 1;
  transition: width 1s;
}
.actionButton {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
.mobileBox:hover,
:focus {
  background-color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.9);
}
.mobileBox.expand {
  width: 320px;
}
.mobile_nav {
  margin-top: 60px;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  display: none;
}
.mobile_nav.displayMobileNav {
  display: block;
  width: 320px;
}
.mobile_nav li {
  background-color: rgba(52, 152, 219, 0.9);
  padding: 0.6em;
  color: white;
}
.mobile_nav a {
  color: white;
}
.mobile_nav li:hover {
  background-color: rgb(52, 152, 219);
}
.mobile_nav li {
  opacity: 0;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 600ms ease both;
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
  -moz-animation: fadeIn 600ms ease both;
  -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
  -o-animation: fadeIn 600ms ease both;
  -o-animation-play-state: paused;
  animation: fadeIn 600ms ease both;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="mobile_navigation">
  <div class="actionButton">
    <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h fa-2x first"></i>
  </div>
  <ul class="mobile_nav">
    <li class=""><a href="http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_list.asp">About Me</a>
    </li>
    <li class=""><a href="http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_list.asp">Portfolio</a>
    </li>
    <li class=""><a href="http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_list.asp">References</a>
    </li>
    <li class=""><a href="http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_list.asp">Say hello!</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/kx27vt6n/4/