# cleanest way to "reset" css position without animating?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm building an "odometer" unit using JS (backwards compatibility) & CSS3.

It works until the number hits 9 then it spins all the way back to 0 quickly.  So I need to correct the position but the fact that it's animating makes it a bit tricky.  The only way I know of to do it is to disable `transition` (add a class), update the position, re-enable `transition` (remove class).

Is there a more straight-forward way?

**tl;dr** -- Basically I need to reset `transform: translateY(-10em)` to `transform: translateY(0)` without animating the transition

Answer (score 0):

If interpret Question correctly you could use `animation-fill-mode` set to `backwards` or `both`

Comment: I'm not using CSS animations, but just the `transition` property.  Basically I need to reset `transform: translateY(-10em)` to `transform: translateY(0)` without animating the transition

Comment: @zyklus Using `css` or `javascript`?

Comment: just javascript

Comment: Can you include `html`, `css`, `javascript`  example of issue at Question? Are you trying to reset the property at conclusion of transition, or user action?

Comment: Basically I have a spinner.  Using JS I update `transform: translateY(-1em)` ... `-9em`, which counts from 0->9.  There is a 2nd 0 at `-10em`, and then I need to "jump back" to the first 0 (`0em`), but without animating

Comment: You can remove the `style` attribute at the element, or remove the `className` where `css` `transition` properties are attached to the element. Then set element to `transform: translateY(0)` , then re-attach transitions. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39521346/delay-queue-function-works-only-on-first-iterration/

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I proposed in my question.  Looking for a more straight-forward way since this seems backwards

Comment: What do you mean by "straight-forward way"? If `transition` is still attached to element, transitions should be expected to be applied. Those properties at `style` element or `classNames` would need to be removed to not be applied. Without being aware of what you mean by "straight-forward", you could use only `style` attribute to set or remove `transition` properties, instead of using both `stylesheet` and `style` element and toggling element `className`s